# How to check in puppet if one of the array items is a sub-string of a given string?

Tags: arrays, puppet

I have a string (an email address)
str = 'call@support.randomain.com'

I have an array with a list of domains :
arr = ['randomain.com', 'test.com', 'support.com']

I need to return true if my string's domain is a part of the array or if its a subdomain of a domain in the array. Return false if the domains are not related.

So far I have tried the in function on the array as a whole and in function while iterating through the elements of the array. Both dont give the right value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform [regular expression pattern matching](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_expressions#comparison-regex-or-data-type-match) against [all array members](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function#any), like this:

```rb
    $email_address = 'call@support.randomain.com'
    [$user, $host] = $email_address.split('@')
    
    $label = $host.split('\.')
    [$hostname, $domainname] = [$label[0], $label[1, -1].join('.')]
    # Now, $hostname is just 'support', whereas $domainname is 'randomain.com'.
    
    $domains = ['randomain.com', 'test.com', 'support.com']
    
    # Sequentially test 'randomain.com', 'test.com', 'support.com'.
    # The `any` lambda finishes as soon as there is a `true` expression.
    $result = $domains.any |$domain| {
            # The last expression determines the “return value”.
            ($domain =~ $host) or ($domain =~ $domainname)
        }
```

You need to install [measures](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function#downcase) for [case‑insensitive matching](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/lang_data_regexp#regex-options), but that’s beside the issue here.